# Is it possible to monitor a C# webservice?

Tags: c#, web-services, iis

Is it possible to moinitor a C# webservice hosted internally on a public facing IIS server?

**Update -** All I need is to make sure that the service is up and running.

If so - what is the best approach?

Thanks in advance,

James

Comment: What sort of monitoring do you want to do? up/down, number of calls, etc?

Comment: Could you be more specific what kind of monitoring you want? A simple alive check from nagios, or some detailed statistics...

Comment: Good point - the type of monitoring I am trying to achieve would help! :-) - see my original question for update.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Information Services have performance counters that can be used to monitor the active Web and FTP connections...

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc728306%28WS.10%29.aspx

```
       To monitor active Web and FTP connections in IIS 6.0

     1.
  Open Administrative Tools, and then click Performance.
     2.
  Right-click the System Monitor details pane, and then click Add Counters.
     3.
  Do one of the following:
      * To monitor any computer on which the monitoring console is run, click Use local computer counters.
  -or-
      * To monitor a specific computer, regardless of where the monitoring console is run, click Select counters from computer, and specify a computer name or IP address.
     4.
  In Performance object, click:
      * Web Service to monitor active Web connections.
  -or-
      * FTP Service to monitor active FTP connections.
     5.
  Click Select counters from list, and select Current Connections.
     6.
  Click All instances.
     7.
  Click Add, and then click Close.
```